# How can I consistently overwrite JSS styles which have indeterminate suffixes?

Tags: reactjs, jss, css-in-js

I’m looking for advice around `@material-ui/core` in react,

#### TLDR;

I would appreciate a consistent approach for handling CSS-in-js generated classNames which have indeterminate numeric suffixes, while still using `@material-ui/core`'s `styled()` function if possible.

#### Specifically

“the class names generated by `@material-ui/core/styles` are non-deterministic” (https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#class-names), but so far at my company the projects I’ve been on have used the `styled()` function for wrapping components to apply styles.

It works great, until I want to overwrite how one of the pseudo-classes applies to the root element that I’m styling. At which point, if I try to use a regular old class-selector to take control of the styling in ta specific state, it’ll work if there’s no suffix on the class, but as soon as the JSS generated className has a numeric suffix, it breaks.

> When I say "suffix" I'm referring to how a component's root className might be `.makeStyles-root` but when the className is generated for that specific instance, it likely has a numeric suffix appended: `.makeStyles-root-123`

#### For example:

Component: `InputLabel` https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/#inputlabel-api
I want to fiddle with the transform that happens, which comes from `.MuiInputLabel-formControl`, but then that transform is overwritten by `.MuiInputLabel-shrink`.

If I try using a regular class selector:

```
export const InputLabel = styled(MuiInputLabel)({
  `&.MuiInputLabel-formControl`: {
    transform: 'translate(2px, 8px) scale(1)',
  },
  `&.MuiInputLabel-shrink`: {
    transform: 'translate(0) scale(0.6)',
  },
});
```

It works only if the JSS class doesn’t have a suffix,

and if I try using the rule names (I don’t think it’s actually supported with `styled()`)

```
export const InputLabel = styled(MuiInputLabel)({
  formControl: {
    transform: 'translate(2px, 8px) scale(1)',
  },
  shrink: {
    transform: 'translate(0) scale(0.6)',
  },
});
```

It just applies invalid rules to the element:

```
    formControl: [object Object]
    shrink: [object Object];
```

I've also tried passing `classes` (but that didn't seem to work at all)

```
export const InputLabel = styled((props) => (
  <MuiInputLabel
    classes={{
      formControl: {
        transform: 'translate(2px, 8px) scale(1)',
      },
      shrink: {
        transform: 'translate(0) scale(0.6)',
      },
    }}
    {...props}
  />
))({});
```

#### Further Notes

- I don’t want to use a theme override (which I imagine would enable the use of those rules here) because I don’t want this styling to apply to all instances of a InputLabel
- so that leaves me leaning towards using the hook api /  makeStyles() : https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api

  - But that doesn’t lend itself well to current patterns with style files.

#### Related

- I've seen these similar questions:

  - [jss to override a material-ui nondeterministic class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50537292/8479303)
  - [How override material ui style with hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827048/how-override-material-ui-style-with-hooks)
  - the difference is that I'm trying to avoid using the hook api if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it isn't possible to do this with `styled()`,

so I've just gone with what other posts have suggested and used `makeStyles()`.

However I have used a bit of a mash-up of the two, so that I can still keep my styling in a separate file.

```
const useLabelStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.text.primary,
  },
  formControl: {
    transform: 'translate(2px, 8px) scale(1)',
  },
  shrink: {
    transform: 'translate(0) scale(0.6)',
  },
}));

export const InputLabel = styled((props) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useLabelStyles(theme);
  return (
    <MuiInputLabel
      classes={classes}
      {...props}
    />
  );
})({});
```